# verify these three differential operators form a lie algebra

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-algebras

I am self studying Lie algebra topic at the basic level. however it is not really clear for me what do a pair of brackets mean exactly?I have collected a bunch of criteria for two operators to form a lie algebra. however I can not find a clear example how to apply them. I appreciate a step by step help
for example do $D_x$ and $xD_x$ and $x^2D_x$ form a lie algebra?

Answer (score 1):

$[D_x,xD_x](f)=D_x(xD_x(f))-xD_x(D_x(f))=D_x(xf')-xD_x(f')=f'+xf"-xf"=f'=D_x(f)$

Compute $[D_x,x^2D_x], [xD_x,x^2D_x]$ and show that they are elements of the vector space generated by $D_x, xD_x$ and $x^2D_x$.

Comment: Thanks. I did the algebra and the jacobi property is not met. hence I am to conclude they do not form a lie algebra but the textI am studying is claiming they form a lie algebra. actually this is an example of lie algebra. since there is no problem solved in the text, I am confused.

Comment: @BesMath: If the Lie bracket $[A,B]$ is defined as commutator $AB-BA$ where products and difference come from an associative algebra structure, then the Jacobi identity is automatically satisfied. This is probably the case in your source, and assumed in this answer: multiplication with $x$ and differentiation $D_x$ are understood as elements of some associative algebra $End_K(F)$ where $K$ is some field and $F$ is some vector space of differentiable functions (or subspace thereof, e.g. polynomials) $K \rightarrow K$. If not, clarify in your question what $x$ and $D_x$ are supposed to mean.

Comment: @BesMath: furthermore, as a remark on proper phrasing, the statement that "operators $D, E, F$ (etc) form a Lie algebra'' is not a rigorous formal mathematical statement. What is one to make of it? Given any subset of a pre-defined Lie algebra it will generate a Lie-subalgebra, so if that is what you mean by those three operators ''forming'' a Lie algebra then of course they will. If you want to more specifically investigate whether those three operators will constitute a basis of the vector space structure subjacent to the algebra they generate, then this should be worded accordingly.